# Regarding flagging

Tags: bug, flag-history

I've recently flagged a question and it was marked as helpful.

But it shows otherwise in **my flagging history**.

[image: 1 hour ago]

I don't think I've ever flagged a comment and I don't remember being declined.. (I've only flagged one question so far.) Is there a bug or have I misinterpreted the content in my flagging history?

And in addition to that, I would like to suggest that there is a small grammatical error here. I think the "flags" in *1 moderator attention flags* should be singular.

Comment: I wonder if you flagged a comment a while back, especially since you've held an account for 9 months.

Comment: @simchona I'm not sure. I don't remember going through the procedure. And I'm not so evil to flag an innocent comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct; however, I can only interrogate the flag system for post flags and not comment flags, so any such investigation would have to be done by a dev.

Regarding the singular/plural issue, I refer you to [Jeff's tweet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694) (Jeff is one of the cofounders of Stack Exchange) and to [previous discussions on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/89334). [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Comment: Oh.. Jeff.... I couldn't help but found a singular/plural issue again....